# CustomScaffold with always-on side menu for desktop causes rendering issues or content misalignment

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I want to achieve the functionality present in the screenshot. I have created a custom scaffold that displays a side-menu which is always on on desktop and adds a responsive margin to every screen.

In the content section I have the page title, a button and several filter chips that filter based on category and a column with several rows of cards (GridView is didn't keep my card's constant aspect). If I don't have any cards in a category, the row with the title + buttons move in the center of the screen. What am I doing wrong in my scaffold and how can I achieve this result without encountering this issue or Rendering problems?

```
class CustomScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget body;
  final double desktopBreakpoint;

  const CustomScaffold({
    Key? key,
    required this.body,
    this.desktopBreakpoint = 800,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        bool isDesktop = constraints.maxWidth > desktopBreakpoint;

        return Scaffold(
          appBar: !isDesktop
              ? AppBar(
                  backgroundColor: drawerBgColor,
                  foregroundColor: menuBtnColor,
                  leading: Builder(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.menu), //TODO change icon
                      onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : null,
          drawer: isDesktop ? null : CustomDrawer(),
          body: Row(
            children: [
              if (isDesktop) CustomDrawer(),
              Flexible(
                fit: FlexFit.loose,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: ResponsiveMarginWrapper(
                    child: body,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class ResponsiveMarginWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const ResponsiveMarginWrapper({super.key, required this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double horizontal = calculateHorizontalMargin(screenWidth);
    double vertical = calculateVerticalMargin(screenWidth);

    EdgeInsets margin = EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: horizontal, vertical: vertical);
    return Container(
      margin: margin,
      child: child,
    );
  }
}


class AllGroupsScreen extends GetView<GroupController> {
  const AllGroupsScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          const SizedBox(height: 1.5 * fontSize),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              const Text("All Groups", style: headingText),
              const SizedBox(width: 1.5 * fontSize),
              _buildCreateGroupBtn(),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 1.5 * fontSize),
          _buildFilterChips(),
          const SizedBox(height: 1.5 * fontSize),
          _buildCardGrid(context),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCardGrid(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(
      () {
        if (controller.isLoading.value) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
        double horizontalSpacing = fontSize;
        double drawerWidth = screenWidth > 800 ? drawerMaxWidth : 0;
        double responsiveMargin = calculateHorizontalMargin(screenWidth);
        double availableWidth = screenWidth - drawerWidth - (2 * responsiveMargin);

        int numberOfColumns = ((availableWidth - horizontalSpacing) / (groupCardWidth + horizontalSpacing)).floor();

        List<Widget> rows = [];
        for (int i = 0; i < controller.filteredGroups.value.length; i += numberOfColumns) {
          List<Widget> rowChildren = [];
          for (int j = 0; j < numberOfColumns; j++) {
            int index = i + j;
            if (index < controller.filteredGroups.value.length) {
              final group = controller.filteredGroups.value[index];
              rowChildren.add(GroupCard(group));
            }
          }
          rows.add(
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: numberOfColumns == 1
                  ? MainAxisAlignment.center // Center the children if there's only one column
                  : MainAxisAlignment.start, // Otherwise, align to the start
              children: rowChildren,
            ),
          );
        }
        return Column(children: rows);
      },
    );
  }

  CustomButton _buildCreateGroupBtn() {
    return CustomButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Get.toNamed(Routes.createGroup);
      },
      child: const Text('Create New'),
    );
  }

  Obx _buildFilterChips() {
    return Obx(
      () {
        final categories = controller.categoryController.categoryNames;
        return Wrap(
          spacing: fontSize / 2,
          children: categories.map((String category) {
            return CustomFilterChip(
              category: category,
              isSelected: controller.selectedCategories.contains(category),
              onSelected: (bool selected) {
                if (selected) {
                  controller.selectedCategories.add(category);
                } else {
                  controller.selectedCategories.remove(category);
                }
                controller.filterGroupsByCategory(controller.selectedCategories.toList());
              },
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If I did not miss anything, your main content can be nullable, it shrinks when there is no content so the your column as well. If you did not try, I can suggest you to add a Sizedbox.shrink with a if block to control the controller.filteredGroups.value == 0

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Sizedbox.expand() works when I don't have any filtered value. However, when I only have for example 1 row instead of 2, the content still moves. I've managed to finally fix it by using a Flexible with Listview.builder() and removing the SingleChildScrollView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it by removing the `SingleChildScrollView` from the CustomScaffold and adapting the AllGroupsScreen to use a `Flexible` with a `ListView.builder()`

```
class AllGroupsScreen extends GetView<GroupController> {
  const AllGroupsScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          const SizedBox(height: 1.5 * fontSize),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              const Text("All Groups", style: headingText),
              const SizedBox(width: 1.5 * fontSize),
              _buildCreateGroupBtn(),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 1.5 * fontSize),
          _buildFilterChips(),
          const SizedBox(height: 1.5 * fontSize),
          _buildCardGrid(context),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCardGrid(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(() {
      if (controller.isLoading.value) {
        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }

      double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
      double horizontalSpacing = fontSize;
      double drawerWidth = screenWidth > 800 ? drawerMaxWidth : 0;
      double responsiveMargin = calculateHorizontalMargin(screenWidth);
      double availableWidth = screenWidth - drawerWidth - (2 * responsiveMargin);
      int numberOfColumns = ((availableWidth - horizontalSpacing) / (groupCardWidth + horizontalSpacing)).floor();

      return Flexible(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: (controller.filteredGroups.value.length / numberOfColumns).ceil(),
          itemBuilder: (context, rowIndex) {
            int start = rowIndex * numberOfColumns;
            int end = start + numberOfColumns;
            List<Widget> rowChildren = [];
            for (int index = start; index < end; index++) {
              if (index < controller.filteredGroups.value.length) {
                final group = controller.filteredGroups.value[index];
                rowChildren.add(GroupCard(group));
              }
            }
            return Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: numberOfColumns == 1 ? MainAxisAlignment.center : MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: rowChildren,
            );
          },
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  double computeGridHeight() {
    double spacing = 20.0;
    int maxRows = 2;
    return (maxRows * groupCardHeight) + ((maxRows - 1) * spacing);
  }

  CustomButton _buildCreateGroupBtn() {
    return CustomButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Get.toNamed(Routes.createGroup);
      },
      child: const Text('Create New'),
    );
  }

  Obx _buildFilterChips() {
    return Obx(
      () {
        final categories = controller.categoryController.categoryNames;
        return Wrap(
          spacing: fontSize / 2,
          children: categories.map((String category) {
            return CustomFilterChip(
              category: category,
              isSelected: controller.selectedCategories.contains(category),
              onSelected: (bool selected) {
                if (selected) {
                  controller.selectedCategories.add(category);
                } else {
                  controller.selectedCategories.remove(category);
                }
                controller.filterGroupsByCategory(controller.selectedCategories.toList());
              },
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```